# dplyr summarize grouped data with another column

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, data-manipulation, summarize

I have a data frame `pop.subset <-`:

```
state  location   pop
WA     Seattle    100
WA     Kent       20
OR     foo        30
CA     foo2       80
```

I need the city in each state with the lowest population stored in a data.frame. 
I have:

```
result <- pop.subset %>% 
          group_by(state) %>%
          summarise(min = min(pop))
```

This returns the data.frame:

```
state   min
WA      20
...    .... etc
```

But I need the city too. I tried including location in the `group_by` function like so: `group_by(state, location)`, but then this gives the min each city paired with a state instead of the state with the city like so:

```
state location pop
WA    Seattle  100
WA    Kent     20
foo   foo      foo
```

Is there is a simple solution I missing? I want my result to be like so:

```
state location pop
WA    Kent     20
...   ...      ... etc.
```

Comment: Can you edit this question so as the code and data match. Currently you have `State`, `Location` and `Pop` in the data frame, but `state` (lower-case 's'), `location` (lower-case 'l') and `both_sexes_2012` (how does that relate to `Pop`?) in the code.

Comment: Oh sorry I copied some old code, fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to group by `state`, then filter for `min(pop)`:

```
pop.subset %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  filter(pop == min(pop)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  state location   pop
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1    WA     Kent    20
2    OR      foo    30
3    CA     foo2    80
```

Comment: you're totally right! thanks I am not sure why I didn't see that. Tried to over complicate it with the summarise function.

Comment: It would seem intuitive to use `summarise`, the key thing is the grouping. If you group on A + B then the summary is for A + B, not for B.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
result <- pop.subset %>% 
              group_by(state, location) %>%
              summarise(min = min(both_sexes_2012))
```

Comment: I tried that but then it pairs states and cities together instead of the minimum city within each state. state location pop. E.g. returns WA, Seattle 100 and WA, Kent, 20 instead of just WA, Kent, 20

Answer (score 0):

I understand, this solves it:

```
library(tibble)

data<-tribble(~state,  ~location,   ~pop,
       "WA",     "Seattle",    100,
       "WA",    "Kent",       20,
       "OR",     "foo" ,       30,
       "CA",     "foo2" ,      80

)

library(dplyr)

data%>%group_by(state)%>%summarise(location=location[which.min(pop)]
                                   ,min=min(pop))


# A tibble: 3 x 3
  state location   min
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1    CA     foo2    80
2    OR      foo    30
3    WA     Kent    20
```

Comment: This is great too!